# Excel: Find Col A Value from Range of B and C

Tags: excel

I have two sheets. 
Sheet1 with list of values in Column A
Sheet 2 has Value range as below

Sheet1:

```
COLA
1
5
6
10
12
```

Sheet2

```
COLA COLB
1
2
3    7
```

How do I do find out which value matches in Sheet 1 from sheet Sheet2 ? In above example, I want to have value TRUE in Column B of Sheet 1 in front of 1, 5, 6 value since it is part of Sheet 2

Comment: how is 5 and 6 part of sheet 2?  I do not see those numbers anywhere.

Comment: Do you mean if it falls between any of the ranges - for example if they are between 3 and 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3<=A1)*(((Sheet2!$B$1:$B$3<>"")*(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$3)+(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$3="")*(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3))>=A1))>0
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH($A1,Sheet2!A:A,0))
```

Comment: I am sorry, format was not right. Sheet2 has two colA From and COLB - TO value.

Comment: Do you mean that you also want to search in Column B. For example, if there were a 7 in Sheet1, do you want a TRUE next to it?

Comment: I want to have TRUE next to it if value matches in sheet 2 in from and to range. e.g. Sheet2 has 1   7, it will put True in front of all values 1,2,3,4,5,6 if it is there. It will lookup value as range from ColA and B on sheet.